# Can android read the serial number of the USB charger

Tags: android

Is there any way an Android device can read the serial number (or any other id) of the USB charger?
The charger is a fully functional USB host and that not only power wires are used.

I have tried to use the USBAccessory (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html), but I always get null as a result of getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY).

best regards,
Ivan